# Find number of element in string with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a function, this function receive a string in argument. The content of this variable is HTML code. I'd like know number of HTML element with the class `.myClass`

```
function MyTest(myData){
    //get how many element with .myClass are in myData
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is pretty much jQuery 101.

```
function myTest(myData) {    
  return $( '.myClass', myData ).length;
}

// Usage:
myTest( '<p><span class="myClass">Hello</span> <span class="myClass">world</span></p>' );
// => 2
```

Comment: It's strange, in "myData", I have this HTML code : <div class="myClass">Testing</div> and I get 0 all the time with your code

Comment: For one reason or another jQuery ignores the outermost element. If necessary wrap it in another div, e.g. `<div> <div class="myClass">Testing</div> </div>`.

Comment: Thank you @Jordan. To overcome jQuery ignoring the outermost element, we can also move the identifying class to any inner element.

Answer (score 0):

you can use length function

where :

1. .gradeX =>is your selector of the element
2. n=> int and holds number of your objects

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() { 

       var n = $(".gradeX").length;  
       alert(n);  } 

   }
   ```
3. your jquery linq to reference the methods:
   http://api.jquery.com/length/ alternative is: http://api.jquery.com/size/

you can have a look here:

http://live.datatables.net/uzelux/edit#javascript,html