# How to get number of html elements in a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get number of HTML elements (HTML tags) in a string?

For example I have this string:

```
<div> some text
     <div>
           <label>some text</label>
     </div>
</div>
```

Now how would I find number of html tags in this string? The result in the case above will be 3.

I did tried this, thought it will work but it didn't:

```
$('*').length;
```

Comment: Check below code is helpful or not..

Comment: I am confused. Why a string? Couldn't you just traverse the DOM with .each() and have an incrimentor output your total?

Comment: am giving a try to each of the answer @Sahal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var s = "<div> some text<div><label>some text</label></div></div>";   
var length = $(s).find('*').andSelf().length;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jCW7Z/

Comment: Why do you need the `.andSelf()`? It's odd that the outer `<div>` doesn't get matched.

Comment: @Blender Do you mean `andSelf` is redundant? The first `div` is wrapper element, it has 2 descendant elements + 1 === 3?

Comment: For some reason I thought jQuery would create another outer wrapper element to wrap everything. It seems like all top-level elements will become wrapper elements: `$('<div><b></b></div><div><b></b></div>').find('*').length === 2`

Comment: @Blender Yes, that's true, all top-level elements become wrapper elements.

Comment: @undefined can we get this totall length without counting these tags <b>,<i>,<span> ?

Comment: @atif Yes, you can use `not` method `$(s).find('*').andSelf().not('b, i, span').length`

Comment: thanks @undefined, i was using filter, it was working for one tag but not for more

Comment: You could also use the form: $('<div>').append( $(s) ).find('*:not(b):not(i)').length

Answer (score 2):

If you're using jQuery (and it looks like you are), the easiest way would be to use code similar to the following:

```
var count = $( yourString ).find('*').andSelf().length
```

However, if you're using vanilla javascript, the implementation would look more like this:

```
var temp = document.createElement('div');
temp.innerHTML = yourString;

var count = temp.getElementsByTagName('*').length;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Get all elements in the document (document.getElementsByTagName('*'))
2. Do a regular expression match on the element's className attribute for each element

---

You can use jQuery: $("html *") which will return all elements between the html tags

1. for names you must use $("html *").attr('name')
2. for values $("html *").val() or $("html *").attr('value')

Answer (score 0):

Possible way to do it: http://api.jquery.com/length/

check out [Find number of element in string with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868741/find-number-of-element-in-string-with-jquery)

for example

> $( '.myClass', myData ).length;

(although this might not show outermost tags)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this,

Put the string in to some hidden `div` like

```
$('#myHiddenDiv').html(string);
```

then

You can gen number of children under it

This will tell you number of html elements under the body

```
var count = $("#myHiddenDiv> *").length;
```

or:

```
var count = $("#myHiddenDiv").children().length;
```

Your div will be like this

```
<div id="myHiddenDiv" style="display:none"></div>
```

Comment: string will be dynamic mean, I will be getting it on click of iframe

Answer (score 0):

A small, self documenting, example :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>List Elements</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>some text
    <div>
        <label>some text</label>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
var x=document.getElementsByTagName('*');
console.log(x.length)
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
    console.log(x[i]);
}
</script>
</body>

</html>
```